# Shiny, getting an object to update with two different means, automatically and with actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm running a relatively complex app at the company I'm working for, but the underlying problem I'm having seems to be something simple.

Very briefly, I have a database that comes from a googlesheet that is being updated continuously.
The idea of the app is to read the data from this googlesheets every certain time interval, in addition, there must be an actionButton that allows you to manually update this data.

After this, the data is processed in different graphs and tables.

The main problem is that I can only get it to work for one of the methods (automatic update), while the other method is ignored by the app (manual update).

As the database I'm using is private I can't share it, but a snippet of the code is as follows.

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets4)


ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("update_meetings", "Press to update meetings")

  renderTable("table_meetings")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_meetings <- eventReactive(input$update_meetings, {
    
    range_speedread("URL of database")
    
  })
  
  data_meetings <- reactive({
    
    invalidateLater(300000, NULL)
    
    range_speedread("URL of database")
    
  })  
}

output$table_meetings <- renderTable({

    data_meetings()

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this code, the database is updated when the app is opened, and automatically every time interval, but pressing the button does not activate the automatic update (it just gets ignored).

It seems to me that the problem is that I am associating a reactive variable to the same object with two different methods (using eventReactive() and reactive() itself), and it is not allowing them to overlap.

Any ideas for a fix? I had the idea of unifying both methods in a single object, but I don't know how I could do that with the input of eventReactive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating two reactives with the same name. What you actually need is a single reactive (or a reactiveVal, to be specific), that can be changed in multiple ways.
Let's try it like this, change the server to read:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_meetings <- reactiveVal(NULL)
    
  observeEvent(input$update_meetings, {
    
    data_meetings(range_speedread("URL of database"))
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    invalidateLater(300000, NULL)
    
    data_meetings(range_speedread("URL of database"))
    
  })  
}
```